# SharePoint dropdown (None) default change . Jquery code

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, drop-down-menu, default

Any jquery code to change the default (None) in my SharePoint dropdown control.

It does not appear that (None) is actually my default as it does not really send (None).

I'd like to change it to (Please Select).

Thanks.

Comment: Is `(None)` always the first item in your dropdown control?

Comment: yes. Something SharePoint forces on the rendered control.  None with a value of nothing. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/F7PPK/

```
$("#mySelect option:eq(0)").text("Please Select").val("What you want sent here")
```

Comment: Thanks, but tried $('select[title$=Issue Type] options:eq(0)').text("Please Select").val(""); and $("#Issue_x0020_Type options:eq(0)").text("Please Select").val(""); to get to this:  <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Issue_x0020_Type" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Issue_x0020_Type')}"/>  with no luck.  I know this found it $('select[title$=Issue Type]').change(function(){

Comment: Rendered code looked like this: <nobr>Issue Type</nobr></H3></td><td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none"><select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_44df98f7_f371_4b1c_aacc_d8ee696a638f$ff2_1$ctl00$Lookup" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_44df98f7_f371_4b1c_aacc_d8ee696a638f_ff2_1_ctl00_Lookup" title="Issue Type"> <option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option>

Comment: @cyberpine - typo in my selector (corrected above).  It should be singular `option`, not `options`.  Sorry! Try now.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will change the default text of all select controls to "Please Select" instead of "(None)":

```
$('select option[value="0"]').text("Please Select")
```

This code will do the same but only for select controls with a specific title:

```
$('select[title="your field title"] option[value="0"]').text("Please Select")
```

I used this when working with Sharepoint 2010, not sure if it works with all versions or not, but since it's generic jQuery code with nothing SP specific, I think it will.